# Read Connected Phone Properties Programmatically on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, powershell, winapi

I am working on my client project . It is an application for a mobile shop to place order and find device details and keep track of all the orders. There i required phone imei or serial number to fetch more details about the device from an API .

i need these details
[image: Device Properties Window]

Is this possible to get device properties Programmatically ?

Comment: You've added a lot of language tags and looks like you're fishing for a response in any language. You should target the `winapi` tag instead

Comment: Yes i need solution in any compiled language possible , My main app is in electronjs.